# How to make chatbot send an API post call with a raw body (JSON)

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to do an API post call in .net core. In the call there needs to be a JSON body. I keep getting a 400 bad request error.

**Code:**

```
public async Task<DialogTurnResult> ProcessConsentAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var convInfoState = await _accessors.ConvInfoState.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new ConvInfoState());

    if (convInfoState.GivenConsent)
    {
        ItsMeRequestModel RequestModel = new RequestModel
        {
            token = "******-******-*****-****",
            service = "login",
            scopes = "profile",
            locale = "nl",
            redirecturl = "https://example.com",
            phonenumber = "+32470603589",
        };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RequestModel);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "example.com", json);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(AllDialogs.Greeting);
    }

    return await stepContext.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the API project as well? 400 indicates that your endpoint is expecting something different. I would guess that your model is not serialized the way your endpoint expects it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Debugging

I debugged this using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for testing and then got it working within my bot. I recommend using this approach when debugging HTTP requests to help narrow the problem down. If you run your request through Postman, you see:

```
{
    "message": "The scopes must be an array.",
    "status": 400
}
```

and

```
{
    "message": "The redirectUrl field is required.",
    "status": 400
}
```

You can also debug with `HttpClient` by adding this line after `var response = await...`:

```
var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

which would produce:

[image: 400 error in Visual Studio]

### So, to fix this, use:

```
ItsMeRequestModel itsMeRequestModel = new ItsMeRequestModel
{
    token = "******-******-*****-****",
    service = "login",
    scopes = new string[] { "profile" },
    locale = "nl",
    redirectUrl = "https://example.com",
    phonenumber = "+32470603589",
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
    "https://api.sandbox.cmdisp.com/itsme/v1/transactions", itsMeRequestModel);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

**Changes from your code:**

- `scopes` is an array, which fixes the "must be an array" error
- `redirectUrl` has a capital U, which fixes the "redirectUrl field is required" error
- No need to serialize the JSON, since `PostAsJsonAsync` accepts JSON

#### Accessing the API response in a Dialog

There's a couple of different ways you can use this within botframework. In either case, you'll want to:

Define a response struct:

```
struct loginResponse
{
    public string transactionToken { get; set; }
    public string authenticationUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Capture the response in a variable (after `var response = await...`):

```
var contents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<loginResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

From there, you have two options:

**1. Instead of beginning a new dialog, I'd just add a step to your waterfall dialog and pass the response to the next step:**

```
return await stepContext.NextAsync(contents);
```

You then access that information in the next step from `stepContext.Result`

**2. Pass it into a new waterfall dialog (like it looks like you're currently attempting):**

```
return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(AllDialogs.Greeting, contents);
```

You can then access this from within your `AllDialogs.Greeting` dialog with:

```
var response = (loginResponse)stepContext.Options;
```

### Note:

OP is using the [itsme API from CM Telecom](https://docs.cmtelecom.com/en/itsme/v1#transaction). You can see in the documentation that it expects an array for `scopes` and that the U in `redirectUrl` is capitalized. Easy mistakes to miss.

Comment: Worked fine for me! Thanks!